# FCKEDITOR security issue

Tags: security, drupal-6, drupal-modules, fckeditor

I run FCKEDITOR 6.x-2.3 on a drupal 6 website, a bunch of hacker team worked to see if there is any security issue on website and they found some vulnerabilities with FCKEDITOR, an anonymous user can upload files to the server using some uploader like [this one](http://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/17644/) to the server.

for an anonymouse user I can access direcotries such as:

> sites/all/modules/fckeditor/fckeditor/editor/filemanager/browser/default/browser.html
>
> sites/all/modules/fckeditor/fckeditor/editor/filemanager/browser/default/frmupload.html

to upload my uploader file. is there a way to fix it? or I should forget about using FCKEDITOR or any other wysiwyg editors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update your FCKEditor module (check: http://drupal.org/node/1482442)

Or, 
you can use CKEditor instead of FCKEDITOR. See: http://drupal.org/project/ckeditor

I have faced similar security issue using CKEditor. And I have following the below steps:

**Here is the process to update ckeditor and ckfinder:**

1. Update CKeditor version 6.x—1.13
2. Download CK Finder  latest version 2.3
3. Unzip the ckfinder in sites/all/module/contrib/ckeditor/ckfinder
4. Open /all/module/contrib/ckeditor/ckfinder/config.php
5. Comment out the CheckAuthentication() function
   [image]
6. Add the below two lines
   [image]
7. $baseUrl may differ depends on products.
8. Open /contrib/ckeditor/ckfinder/config.js
9. add the below lines:
   [image]
10. Note: I would like to request all to prepare a set of allowed and denied extensions
    [image]

One more additional issue: Add cookie_domain in sites/default/settings.php file.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @zvzdhk, Thanks for the suggestion. I have updated my answer for a similar issue I have already faced using CKEditor module.